# Чтение из файла конфигурации scala/playframework 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework

в более ранних версиях читалось на ура с использованием

```
val value = Play.current.configuration.getString("confKey")
```

но play 2.5 выдается warning

> method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead

что означает - ребята используйте `Dependency Injection`

Хорошо, пишу следующий код:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Configuration

class SomeClass @Inject() (playconfiguration: Configuration) {
    val someConfigValue: String = playconfiguration.getString("someConfKey").get
}
```

Нужен доступ к конфигу `из объекта`. Ок, наследуем класс и передаем ему конфигурацию, тут у меня и возникает проблема, я не понимаю где ее взять

```
object SomeObj extends SomeClass(Configuration.и что дальше?`){
    def getSomeConfigValue(): String = someConfigValue
}
```

интересует чтение как из `application.conf` так и из `somePath/someFile.conf`

В сухом остатке, вопрос можно переформулировать - "**как прочитать значение ключа из application.conf либо *.conf в объекте, минуя warning про DI, то есть не используя `Play.current.configuration` а используя `Dependency Injection`?**"

```
object AnyObj {
    val value = читаем из конфигурационного файла
}
```

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уменя получилось реализовать это следующим образом, для примера прочитаем настройки подключения к бд, создадим файл `services/ConfigReader.scala`

```
package services

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}

class AppConfig @Inject()(playConfig: Configuration) {
  val dbHost: Option[String] = playConfig.getString("mydb.host")
  val dbPort: Option[Long] = playConfig.getLong("mydb.port")
}

object ConfigReader {
  val config = new AppConfig(Configuration.load(Environment.simple()))
  def getDbHost: String = config.dbHost.getOrElse("localhost")
  def getDbPort: Long = config.dbPort.getOrElse(27017)
}
```

пропишем в `conf/application.conf`

```
mydb {
  host = 192.168.0.0
  port = 1234
}
```

Таким образом получим возможность читать конфиг из любого места, просто импортировав `ConfigReader`, например в контроллере

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import services.ConfigReader

class SomeCtrl extends Controller {
  def index = Action { request =>
    Ok(ConfigReader.getDbHost + ":" + ConfigReader.getDbPort.toString)
  }
}
```

Отлично работает с `application.conf`, осталось только понять как прочитать из `*.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю такое наследование невозможно.
Если нужно чтоб в `object` был доступ к зависимостям я вижу два варианта:

1. Передавать зависимость как параметер функции. Из класса в котором тебе необходим эта функция.

   ```
   object SomeObj {
       def getSomeConfigValue(configuration: Configuration): String = {
           configuration
               .getString("play.crypto.secret")
               .getOrElse(sys.error(s"Please configure secret")
       }
   }

   //example
   class MyController @Inject()(configuration: Configuration) extends Controller {

       def index = Action {
           val secret = SomeObj.getSomeConfigValue(configuration)
           println(secret)
           Ok
       }

   }
   ```
2. Создавать объект внутри класса(который лучше делать синглтоном). (Этот метод крайний-крайний случай)

   ```
   @Singleton
   class InjectableClazz @Inject() (configuration: Configuration) {
       object SomeObj {
           def getSomeConfigValue(): String = someConfigValue
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: и как, допустим, в 1ом случае мне прочитать значение ключа из application.conf? как передать его в конструктор?

Comment: @papiroca, добавил пример. Если это не твой случай - то лучше приведи пример ближе к жизни, иначе вопрос слишком абстрактный. Доставать зависимое значение из объекта - обычно это результат не правильного проектирования - и тут надо действовать по ситуации. А ситуацию ты не описал.

Comment: в строчке val secret = SomeObj.getSomeConfigValue(configuration) - какая именно конфигурация будет использована, application.conf? а если я хочу pathToConf/myConf.conf ?

Comment: по поводу проектирования,  например задача, создать класс AppConf, который через `Inject` прочитает указанную мной конфигурацию, затем в любом месте проекта хотелось бы получать доступ к любому значению из конфигурации но при этом не делать new, и не делать Inject, а взять необходимое значение из объекта ConfReader, который унаследует класс AppConf, например `val db = MongoClient(ConfReader.getDbHost, ConfReader.getDbPort) `